# Recurring Word error: "AUTOSAVE FAILED We have not been able to save your recent changes"

Tags: microsoft-word

In the past weeks, one of the documents I regularly edit produces the following error:
[image]

This prompt appears at random times, i.e. not when saving, but also when typing in the doc. The message appears intermintently, i.e. sometimes it goes away after saving, but reappears later, and one is of course no longer confident the doc is safe until you save it as another document, which ends up taking a lot of time.

There is nothing special about the document in terms of contents (several images, but mostly text with basic formatting). It lives in a regular DOCX format.

The suggestions in the threads I found on this error ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftWord/comments/95qh21/office_365_autosave_failed_we_have_not_been_able/), [2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/autosave-failed-we-have-not-been-able-to-save-your/4a7f3c3b-c4e2-43b9-990f-166d89d48bc1?auth=1), [3](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/autosave-failed-message-in-word/3a0d5493-ac78-4e4f-ab51-8dd491de4ab9)) were to:

- paste the contents in a new doc: didn't work (same thing happens with the new doc)
- reboot the PC: also didn't work
- avoid docs downloaded from google drive or onedrive: not the case, doc was created offline
- run Office Repair: not available in my installation
- apply Office updates: these yield the error" Something went wrong (errorcode 30125-28-12029)"
- save doc in 97-2003 format, or in a different path: also didn't work

Am using Word 2019, on Windows 10. Might Word 2021 have fixed this bug?